# Is there a way to lock in a specific row and column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table which gets updated by a process from time to time.  However, in some cases, I would like to enforce overrides to specific rows.  Is there a way that I can without writing a lot of code to handle overrides, etc, just lock a row or field in the database itself?

For example, my table looks like

```
STUDENT | TEST_SCORE_AVG | HOMEWORK_AVG
John    |       92.3     |     88.8
Lisa    |       77.4     |     99.8 
Terry   |       88.0     |     64.5
```

With every new test or homework assignment, the student's averages will change.  However, say the teacher is John's mother, and no matter what, he gets a 100.0 on his homework average.  Is there a way to lock that in so that any program trying to change the value will get bounced back?  I am using MySQL workbench to access my MySQL database (InnoDB)

UPDATE:

I could also make due with a function that locks the full row - meaning that neither `TEST_SCORE_AVG` nor `HOMEWORK_AVG` could ever be changed.  I need the solution to persist over a long period of time, regardless of if the connection is lost.  I want to lock the row until such time that I otherwise unlock it

Comment: Maternal favoritism in school? Say it isn't so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no *practical* way to prevent a single value in a single row from ever changing.

Using just about anything besides MySQL, you could create a CHECK() constraint that guarantees John's homework average is always 100, but I wouldn't call that practical.  On MySQL, you'd have to use a trigger to get the same feature, but again I wouldn't call that practical.

Other answers refer to row-level locking, which really has nothing to do with preventing a single value in a single row from changing.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html):

> InnoDB implements standard row-level locking where there are two types of locks:
>
> - A shared (S) lock permits a transaction to read a row.
> - An exclusive (X) lock permits a transaction to update or delete a row.

You can lock a specific row, but can't lock on a specific row *and* column.

Comment: The OP is asking whether it's possible to prevent one value in one row from ever changing. Row-level locking doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: So how does it work for the row?  The immoral teacher might be able to get by setting both the test and homework grades.  I would need the lock to persist even after the database connection is closed.  I want to basically say "use this value until I tell you otherwise" as a manual override

Comment: @Catcall, it is less ideal but I if it works then it might be good enough

Comment: @sally: It won't work. JYelton was confused by your terminology. Row-level locks (and *locking* in general, when you're talking about databases) has to do with concurrency, not with preventing changes to anything.

Comment: Ah yes, lock as in make readonly, not lock as in prevent two things from modifying at the same time. @Catcall is right; I thought you meant locking for concurrency.